# Question regarding substitution in integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, substitution, electromagnetism

Suppose I want to make the substitution $\mathbf{k}\to-\mathbf{k}$ in the integral $$\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$$ where the domain of integration in $\mathbf{k}$-space is *arbitrary*. According to my course notes we should arrive at

> $$\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\overset{\text{course notes}}{=}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(-\mathbf{k},t)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$$

but I somehow think there should be an *extra minus sign* in this result, since I believe the substitution implies that $\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\to -\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}$.

First let us write $\mathbf{k}'=-\mathbf{k}$, then $$\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}=\mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_y\mathrm{d}k_z=(-\mathrm{d}k_x')(-\mathrm{d}k_y')(-\mathrm{d}k_z')=-\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}'$$ and $$\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}=\boldsymbol{\alpha}(-\mathbf{k}',t)e^{i\mathbf{k}'\cdot\mathbf{r}}.$$ Hence \begin{align}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}&=-\int \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}'\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(-\mathbf{k}',t)e^{i\mathbf{k}'\cdot\mathbf{r}}\\
&=-\int \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(-\mathbf{k},t)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\end{align} where in the last line, I simply renamed the variable of integration. So,

> ***What I think it should read:***
>   $$\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\overset{?}{=}-\int \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}(-\mathbf{k},t)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}.$$

I didn't mention the domain of integration and nor do the course notes, so I assume the arbitrariness of the domain of integration allows us to disregard the minus sign to arrive at the result stated in the course notes. I'm not quite sure, however, so I would really like some help.

Comment: I would agree.  Looks like the minus sign should be there.  Can you write down a simple special case, for example integrating in the interior of a sphere or cube and with $\alpha$ some simple function, for example $\alpha=1$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I think I understand now what my course notes are trying to convey. In fact I believe they (very implicitly) state that the domain of integration is really $\mathbf{k}\in(-\infty,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)\equiv\mathbb{R}^3$. The substitution would cause the $k_x'$- $k_y'$- and $k_z'$-boundaries to be reversed as opposed to those of the original integral, which could then be reverted by absorbing the minus sign three times (since $-1=(-1)(-1)(-1)$).

Comment: So with or without the minus sign?

Comment: It appears the original identity is correct, given you revert the substitution's inversion of the boundaries by absorbing the minus sign.

Comment: And of course, I couldn't have really known that without the domain of integration being specified explicitly ...

Comment: I think I see it.  Even in one dimension it works:  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_\infty^{-\infty} f(-x)\, (-dx) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-x) \, dx.$$  Essentially we are just reflecting the function over all space, but the integral sums to the same value.